# Update a timestamp column

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to all of timestamps in a column the same amount.
I want to write an sql statement like:

update sometable set timecol = timecol + <4 months>;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update sometable set timecol = add_months(timecol,4);
```

See [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions004.htm#SQLRF00603)

Answer (score 1):

```
update sometable set timecol = timecol + interval '4' month;
```

Strangely enough, I can't find this in the Oracle documentation anywhere, but it works on my Oracle XE installation.  It's fairly close to the way PostgreSQL does it, and I believe it's part of one of the SQL standards.

Comment: Yes, using INTERVAL is standard SQL.  BTW, I wonder why you put quotes around '4'?

Comment: Here you go: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00221 Quotes are part of the documented dyntax in Oracle, btw.